# no me deja instalar bcrypt

Tags: nodejs, npm

Esto es lo que me sale en la consola:

> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

"node-pre-gyp" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.22.0 requires a peer of eslint@^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\walfr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-30T19_55_19_309Z-debug.log

Comment: Para instalar bycrpt no deberías de simplemente hacer `npm install bcrypt` ?

Comment: eso hago y me sale el mensaje de arriba en la consola, no se que tengo que hacer, nunca me habia pasado eso